# Limited Spring session for specific tasks

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, session

I'm currently implementing a Web-based application using Spring 4. In my application I allow users to upload files (around 10GB to 100GB big).

Right now, I'm using JavaScript to send huge files in chunks. In the server side I join all chunks into a single file and, at the end, I have the entire file uploaded. That's already working fine.

The problem is: although I'm uploading a big file in chunks, this operation might take a little while to finish. Since I'm using javascript to split up the file and send its chunks using Ajax calls, if the user goes to another page or even refresh the current page the upload stops because the javascript code is removed or refreshed.

I was wondering if there is any mechanism in Spring to create another kind of limited session only for upload purposes. By doing that, I'd let the upload run on this limited session and the current user session wouldn't be affected enabling the user to navigate normally through the application. I've seen in other posts we can actually create session aliases, but I'm not sure how to do that and if that'd solve my problem.

Any other ideas are welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want something the end-user installs?

Comment: I really don't want to force the user to install any other software. But I know it might be the case

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what spring has to do with your client side problem.  I'm no spring expert, but it's all server-side, right?  If the user terminates the current document, how is having an extra user session on the server going to help?  Or, why would having only one session per user be a limiting factor?  From your description, it sounds like any solution would be purely client-side.

Comment: Well... the problem is really at the client-side. But to be able to interact with the server, the client must be authenticated. Having a single session, the user cannot go to any other page until the upload is done. Otherwise, the context on the client side would be lost and the upload would stop. What I want to do is enable the user to upload his files and still be able to click on any other page he wants to.